# C++ header file class declaration

Tags: c++, visual-c++, clion

So in my C++ project, I have my "cards.h" and "cards.cpp" file, and the "cards.h" file declares 3 classes: Card, Deck, Hand

```
class Card {
 private:
       // some private attributes
 public:
       // some public methods
       //.....

       void play(Deck& deck, Hand& hand); // This method plays the card, removes it from the hand, and places it in the deck 
}

class Deck {
private:
       vector<Card> deckCards;
public:
       // some public methods
}

class Hand {
private:
       vector<Card> handCards;
public:
       // some public methods
}
```

The compiler gives me an error in the play method on "Deck" and "Hand" with the error "Unknown type name Deck", "Unknown type name Hand". How can it not see the classes that are declared in the same .h file? Does C++ read the file from top to bottom ?

- I also can't put the Card class at the bottom, because Deck and Hand uses Card
- I have to put all 3 classes in the same file, the "cards.h" file.

Comment: Are you using forward declarations for the 2 classes that are listed below `Card` in the header?

Comment: C++ is specified to allow [single-pass compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-pass_compiler), so just about everything everything is read and processed in the order it's found in the file. At `play`, `Deck` and `Hand` have presumably not been declared because they come later in the file. Since `play` takes references, you should be able to fix this problem with forward declaration as suggested by @drescherjm . If this doesn't work, you'll have to expand the question to contain a [mre] so we can see exactly what you do.

Comment: @drescherjm No I am not, I used it and it worked. Will it cause me some problem though ?

Comment: @user4581301 thank you for the detailed explanation, forward declaration works just fine

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but a `Card` shouldn't know about a `Deck` or a `Hand`, and none of them should rearrange decks or hands. That's another class, perhaps `Game`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct.  C++ needs the declarations to go from top to bottom.
A side note you have incorrect syntax for the class declarations. Each class needs to be terminated with a semicolon after the last closing curly brace.  I tested your example and it works fine.

You can separate the classes into their own files and use forward class declarations since each class needs the other.  Or you can leave them in the same file and add the forward class declaration prior to usage. Like below.

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Deck;
class Hand;

class Card {
private:
    // some private attributes
public:
    // some public methods
    //.....

    void play(Deck& deck, Hand& hand) {}; // This method plays the card, removes it from the hand, and places it in the deck 
};

class Deck {
private:
    vector<Card> deckCards;
public:
    // some public methods
};

class Hand {
private:
    vector<Card> handCards;
public:
    // some public methods
};
```

Comment: I thought the issue was the missing semicolon.  The actual issue is that Card Needs Deck and Hand before declaration. You can fix that with forward class declarations.

Comment: *semicolon* is the character that’s missing.

Comment: I actually have the semicolon in my code, I forgot to paste it in here. But yes, the forward declarations work, thank you !